# CppUnitTestFramework and test for "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, stdvector

I have some code which I would like to test. In case wrong parameters are passed I have access to vector beyond its range. I want to test for this condition. Is it possible to test this code with `CppUnitTestFramework`?

```
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (size() <= _Pos)
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
            _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
            }

 #elif _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 1
        _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size());
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test something then it means that you expect some kind of predictable behavior. Using vector::operator[] to access items out of range detonates undefined behavior. In case of Debug MS VS build you may get an assertion, but in Release build anything can happen. So testing operator[] is pointless and actually it's developer responsibility to make sure that passed index value is correct. But there is also vector::at() method that throws out_of_range exception if the index passed is invalid so you can test it like this:

```
TEST_METHOD(VectorOutOfRangeAccess_Test)
{
    auto out_of_range_thrown{false};
    try
    {
        ::std::vector< int > const values{0, 1, 2};
        values.at(3);
    }
    catch(::std::out_of_range const &)
    {
        out_of_range_thrown = true;
    }
    catch(...){}
    Assert::IsTrue(out_of_range_thrown);
}
```